# How to insert table into Word document in place of text mark?

Tags: c#, datatable, com, ms-word, ms-office

I have `DateTable`. Need to insert it instead of some set of characters in teplate document.

I can replace text-to-text this way (lots of missingObj to avoid the bugs):

```
    using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

    Word._Application application;
    Word._Document document;
    Object missingObj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Object trueObj = true;
    Object falseObj = false;

    private void create_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            application = new Word.Application();
            Object templatePathObj;
            templatePathObj = "template.dot";  

            try {
                document = application.Documents.Add(ref  templatePathObj, 
                    ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
            }
            catch (Exception error) {
                document.Close(ref falseObj, ref  missingObj, ref missingObj);
                application.Quit(ref missingObj, ref  missingObj, ref missingObj);
                document = null;
                application = null;
                throw error;
            }

            object strToFindObj = "%%mark%%";
            object replaceStrObj = "text to replace";
            Word.Range wordRange;
            object replaceTypeObj;
            replaceTypeObj = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            for (int i = 1; i <= document.Sections.Count; i++) {
                wordRange = document.Sections[i].Range;
                Word.Find wordFindObj = wordRange.Find;
                object[] wordFindParameters = new object[15] { strToFindObj, missingObj, 
                    missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, missingObj, 
                    missingObj, replaceStrObj, replaceTypeObj, missingObj, missingObj, 
                    missingObj, missingObj };
                wordFindObj.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
                    null, wordFindObj, wordFindParameters);
        }
        application.Visible = true;
    }
```

What i have to change so this code will take `DataTable` instead of `strToFindObj`?

In this example i replace stuff in `Range`, what is some fragmen of document including tables, format, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> lots of missingObj to avoid the bugs

Target .Net 4.0 or above supports named and optional arguments with COM calls so you wont need to include all the `ref missingObj`. See this MSDN Article: [Named and Optional Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/dd264739.aspx) - *This capability greatly facilitates calls to COM interfaces such as the Microsoft Office Automation APIs.*

---

> What do I have to change so I can search using a `DataTable` instead
>   of string variable `strToFindObj`?

You would have to iterate through the DataTables Row's and Cell's replacing the DataTable cells in the Word Document, eg:

```
foreach(var dr in dt.Rows)
{
  foreach (var cell in dr.ItemArray)
  {
    string strToFind = cell.ToString();
    string replaceStr = "replace old value";
    ReplaceTextInWord(@"C:\Temp\template.docx", strToFind, replaceStr);
  }
}
```

If you find using a DataTable too hard and want a list (like a Dictionary) that's even easier:

```
var listOfTextToReplace = new Dictionary<string,string>();
listOfTextToReplace.Add("%%mark%%","text to replace");
foreach(var item in listOfTextToReplace )
{
    string strToFind = item.Key;
    string replaceStr = item.Value;
    ReplaceTextInWord(@"C:\Temp\template.docx", strToFind, replaceStr);
}
```

---

Here is the **ReplaceTextInWord** method:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
Word._Application application;
Word._Document document;
Object missingObj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Object trueObj = true;
Object falseObj = false;

private void create_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //ReplaceTextInWord("template.dot", "find me", "Found"); <-- Are you sure you want to replace in a Template?
   ReplaceTextInWord(@"C:\Temp\template.docx", "%%mark%%","text to replace");  //I think you want a .DOC or DOCX file
}

private void ReplaceTextInWord(string wordDocFilePath, string strToFind, string replaceStr) {
    application = new Word.Application();
    try {
        //document = application.Documents.Add(ref templatePathObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj); 
        document = application.Documents.Open(wordDocFilePath);  //You need to open Word Documents, not add them, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcyt0y1f.aspx
    }
    catch (Exception error) {
        document.Close(ref falseObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        application.Quit(ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        document = null;
        application = null;
        throw error;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= document.Sections.Count; i++) {
    Word.Range wordRange = document.Sections[i].Range;
    Word.Find findObject = wordRange.Find;
    findObject.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Text = strToFind;
    findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Replacement.Text = replaceStr;

    object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
    application.Visible = true;
}
```

Ref MSDN: [How to: Programmatically Search for and Replace Text in Documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx)